# Call class function inside a closure React native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, closures

I'm new to React native, and got a problem here, I want to use closure instead of lambda at `onChangeText` function:

```
render() {
        return (
            <View style={{padding: 10}}>
                <TextInput style={{height: 40}} placeholder="Type here"
                           onChangeText = {function(t) {
                            this.setState({text: t});
                           }}
                          // onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text: text})}
                />
                <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
                    {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

The problem is inside the closure, `this` is the closure context, not the class context, so I can't call `setState` there. In Java, I just simply remove this and everything OK, but how can I do this in JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Assuming your desired function is already a method on your class. ie:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {

  myMethodThatChangesState() {
    this.setState(...);
  }

  render() {...}
}
```

React requires pure functions. To avoid using lambdas such as:

```
onChangeText={() => this.setState(..)}
```

Bind your method to your class through JavaScript Function's bind method, like so:

```
onChangeText={myMethodThatChangesState.bind(this)}
```

Using `Function.bind(this)` returns a function with the `this` as the last argument - so the `this` will be your React class. ES6 arrow functions perform the same action.

This way you can avoid using arrow functions in your render markup.